# Trouble creating my first Laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, cmd, laravel-artisan

I just started using and watched a youtube video how to start.

I try to make my first controller, so I execute this command:

```
php artisan controller:make WelcomeController
```

I get an exception:

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]                                    
  There are no commands defined in the "controller" namespace.
```

I am executing this in the root folder of the Laravel project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is actually:

```
php artisan make:controller WelcomeController
```

You wrote `controller:make` instead of [`make:controller`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers).

---

In the future you can run just [`php artisan`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan#introduction) and it will list all commands with a short description for each one, that way you can make sure you're running the correct command. If you want more details about a command, like usage and what options it accepts, you can run `php artisan help [command]`. So for your command it would be:

```
php artisan help make:controller
```

Comment: Thank you. It's weird the video actually had wrong instructions.

Comment: @BorutFlis The video you were watching might have been for Laravel 4. It changed to `make:controller` for Laravel 5.